# Nested resources conflict in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

With the following routes I am running into a conflict issue. It seems that both cannot exist together. How can I specify both without conflict? Thanks.

```
 resources :colleges do
    resources :departments
 end

 resources :departments do
    resources :professors
 end
```

the path **new_college_department_path(@college)** produces the url **colleges/1/departments/new** which in turn leads to the following error. I am not sure why the controller professors is listed, since it isn't even part of the route!

```
 Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"professors", :format=>nil, :request_id=>#<department_id: nil, text: nil, goal: nil, accept: nil, post_url: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, u_id: nil, b_id: 1, active: nil>}
```

**Routes:**

```
blog_requests GET    /blogs/:blog_id/requests(.:format)                  requests#index
                       POST   /blogs/:blog_id/requests(.:format)                  requests#create
      new_blog_request GET    /blogs/:blog_id/requests/new(.:format)              requests#new
     edit_blog_request GET    /blogs/:blog_id/requests/:id/edit(.:format)         requests#edit
          blog_request GET    /blogs/:blog_id/requests/:id(.:format)              requests#show
                       PUT    /blogs/:blog_id/requests/:id(.:format)              requests#update
                       DELETE /blogs/:blog_id/requests/:id(.:format)              requests#destroy
                 blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)                                    blogs#index
                       POST   /blogs(.:format)                                    blogs#create
              new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)                                blogs#new
             edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)                           blogs#edit
                  blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)                                blogs#show
                       PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)                                blogs#update
                       DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)                                blogs#destroy
    request_supporters GET    /requests/:request_id/supporters(.:format)          supporters#index
                       POST   /requests/:request_id/supporters(.:format)          supporters#create
 new_request_supporter GET    /requests/:request_id/supporters/new(.:format)      supporters#new
edit_request_supporter GET    /requests/:request_id/supporters/:id/edit(.:format) supporters#edit
     request_supporter GET    /requests/:request_id/supporters/:id(.:format)      supporters#show
                       PUT    /requests/:request_id/supporters/:id(.:format)      supporters#update
                       DELETE /requests/:request_id/supporters/:id(.:format)      supporters#destroy
              requests GET    /requests(.:format)                                 requests#index
                       POST   /requests(.:format)                                 requests#create
           new_request GET    /requests/new(.:format)                             requests#new
          edit_request GET    /requests/:id/edit(.:format)                        requests#edit
               request GET    /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#show
                       PUT    /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#update
                       DELETE /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#destroy
                       GET    /requests(.:format)                                 requests#index
                       POST   /requests(.:format)                                 requests#create
                       GET    /requests/new(.:format)                             requests#new
                       GET    /requests/:id/edit(.:format)                        requests#edit
                       GET    /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#show
                       PUT    /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#update
                       DELETE /requests/:id(.:format)                             requests#destroy
            supporters GET    /supporters(.:format)                               supporters#index
                       POST   /supporters(.:format)                               supporters#create
         new_supporter GET    /supporters/new(.:format)                           supporters#new
        edit_supporter GET    /supporters/:id/edit(.:format)                      supporters#edit
             supporter GET    /supporters/:id(.:format)                           supporters#show
                       PUT    /supporters/:id(.:format)                           supporters#update
                       DELETE /supporters/:id(.:format)                           supporters#destroy
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                                    users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                                    users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                           users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)
```

Comment: what does a rake routes show?

Comment: First, I think you made a typo: `college/1/departments/new`. `departments` should be plural. At what line does the error happen? check the trace, I don't think it has to do with `new_college_department_path(@college)`.

Comment: @Robin Hi, thanks I did make a typo. All I get is the Routing Error... it does not display at what line the error occurs. If I remove the last nested resources, the error goes away and the 'new' action is rendered. However, then other errors pop up since I just removed those resources.

Comment: That print out for `rake routes` looks very wrong for what you say you have listed in your routes file.  What does your entire 'config/routes.rb' file look like?

Comment: You definitely missed a part of what `rake routes` output, since there is no mention of the routes for colleges and departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in a form_for. Routes were ok.

Answer (score 1):

If `professors` is children of `departments` and `departments` if children of `colleges` you can define as below:

```
 resources :colleges do
    resources :departments do
      resources :professors
    end
 end
```

So, your path will be:

```
colleges/1/departments/1/professors/1
```

Comment: It does not seems that the routes are not the problem at this point. However, the Routes docs do say that nesting routes this deeply is a bad idea... will keep at it.

Comment: if you don't want to deep your routes you need to include an extra resources `resources :professors` . [This article](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources) suggests what you are saying, and [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1671632&seqNum=7) suggests the use of `shallow: true`, which I prefer....